# How to find string and delete previous text using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a situation to remove the previous text in a line by finding the specific string.

I have a huge file and wish to delete some unwanted text.

Ex: I have a line as follows:

```
&$GNDTM,W84,,0.0,N,0.0,E,0.0,W84*71
 He    /  [A j  }    .   D   V   Fd     Y       $GLGSV,4,1,13,65,02,318,26,70,06,099,28,71,30,054,35,72,26,356,32*64
```

Here, I need to find a string `$G` and remove the unwanted characters behind it. I need a file to be like this.

```
$GNDTM,W84,,0.0,N,0.0,E,0.0,W84*71
$GLGSV,4,1,13,65,02,318,26,70,06,099,28,71,30,054,35,72,26,356,32*64
```

Can someone help me with a python script?

Comment: Please don't use language tags other than the one actually used in the question, it's confusing and it will most likely attract downvotes.

Comment: does each line start with $G? and if not is there a $G following that should be the start ofthe line?

Comment: Most of the lines start with $G and some with the ASCII characters following with $G. So I need to delete the ASCII Characters before $G print

Comment: globally, Find `(?m)^.+?(\$G)` replace `$1` I believe Python uses the sub function for this.

Comment: could you use something like https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2 to take care of the parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [re - module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) for this task:

```
# create demo file
t = """&$GNDTM,W84,,0.0,N,0.0,E,0.0,W84*71
 He    /  [A j  }    .   D   V   Fd     Y       $GLGSV,4,1,13,65,02,318,26,70,06,099,28,71,30,054,35,72,26,356,32*64"""

with open("f.txt" ,"w") as f:
    f.write(t)


# process demo file
import re

cleaned = []
r = r"^.*?(\$G.*)$"
with open ("f.txt") as f, open ("r.txt","w") as w:
    for l in f:
        m = re.search(r,l)
        if m:
            w.write(m.group(1).rstrip("\n")+"\n")

with open ("r.txt") as r:
    print(r.read())
```

Outputfile:

```
$GNDTM,W84,,0.0,N,0.0,E,0.0,W84*71
$GLGSV,4,1,13,65,02,318,26,70,06,099,28,71,30,054,35,72,26,356,32*64
```

The regex [searches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) for all matches in a line starting with `$G` till the end of the line. If a [match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) is found, writes it into new file.

The regexstring `^.*?(\$G.*)$` means:

```
^   start of line  
  .*? as few anythings as possible
    ( start of captured group
      \$G  literal $ followed by G
      .* anything greedy
    ) end of captured group
$ end of line
```

You might need to add a crlf after your last line or integrate \Z.

Probably better to use youre real data and f.e.  http://regex101.com

Comment: With some modifications on the script for my requirement. This script worked OK. The same method I tried using to find the regex and replace with "space" on Notepad++ that did not work anyway. Thanks for the script which worked OK.